# mongo driver 2.7 missing eval function

Tags: mongodb, .net-core

I am trying to execute the random java scripts which work from mongo command line but I am trying to execute using mongo .net core c# driver I didn't find the eval function in new API, so I created the extension method like this....but it is not working as expected

```
public static async Task<BsonValue> EvalAsync(this IMongoDatabase database, string javascript)
        {
            var client = database.Client as MongoClient;

            if (client == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Client is not a MongoClient");

            var function = new BsonJavaScript(javascript);
            var op = new EvalOperation(database.DatabaseNamespace, function, null);

            using (var writeBinding = new WritableServerBinding(client.Cluster, new CoreSessionHandle(NoCoreSession.Instance)))
            {
                try
                {
                    return await op.ExecuteAsync(writeBinding, CancellationToken.None);
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                   return await Task.FromResult<string>(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }

test script:

db.collection.updateOne(
{"PageId":NumberInt(12)},
{$set:
        {
           "PageName":"testpage",
           "Section":[{
               "SectionId":NumberInt(1),
               "Title":"testpage",
               "Contents":""}],
            "Message":[{
                "MessageId":NumberInt(1),
                "MessageTypeId":NumberInt(2),
                "MessageText":"teswt message."
                 }]
        }
    },
    {upsert: true}
);  

printjson(db.runCommand({getLastError:1}));
```

I am trying to execute the random java scripts which work from mongo command line but I am trying to execute using mongo .net core c# driver I didn't find the eval function in new API, so I created the extension method like this....but it is not working as expected

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? How does your data look like? What error message are you getting?